# does redirecting from grid using javascript increase performance

Tags: asp.net, javascript

does redirecting from grid using javascript increase performance in asp.net

Comment: What do you mean by "redirecting from grid using javascript"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it definetly does increase your performance as there is no postback, user doesn't have to wait. There is no server side processing as well.

Happy coding.

Comment: thanx all of you for your response

Answer (score 1):

Reloading a grid using javascript would increase performance.  Redirecting to another page using javascript, in replacement of a hyperlink or something, would not be much difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript redirect is saving a postback then its definitely improvement in performance otherwise not.